# What is my shell environement?

Tags: shell, path

I decided to post here because my problem deals with Linux issues. I am trying to run Jupiter notebook

```
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ModuleNotFoundError                       Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-13-61fbc0d156c2> in <module>
----> 1 from pyspark.sql import SparkSession

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pyspark'
```

In Jupyter,shell environment and Python executable are disconnected.

```
!echo $PATH
/snap/jupyter/6/bin:/snap/jupyter/6/usr/sbin:/snap/jupyter/6/usr/bin:/snap/jupyter/6/sbin:/snap/jupyter/6/bin:/home/mm/snap/jupyter/common/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games
```

ANd

```
sys.path['/home/mm',
 '/snap/jupyter/6/lib/python37.zip',
 '/snap/jupyter/6/lib/python3.7',
 '/snap/jupyter/6/lib/python3.7/lib-dynload',
 '',
 '/snap/jupyter/6/lib/python3.7/site-packages',
 '/snap/jupyter/6/lib/python3.7/site-packages/IPython/extensions',
 '/home/mm/snap/jupyter/6/.ipython']
```

IF I list packages

```
!pip list
Package Version
------- -------
py4j    0.10.9 
pyspark 3.0.0
```

WHAT IS MY SHELL ENVIRONMENT?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get the shell that you are using:

Default shell:

```
echo $SHELL
```

Your current shell which may or may not be the same as the default:

```
echo $0
```

Two other ways to get your current shell:

```
ps -p $$

printf "%s\n" $0
```

If you want to find all environment varilables, use either of the following two commands:

```
env

printenv
```

The issues that you are having with Jupyter Notebook are possibly due to the way that your Python environment is set up. You can use:

```
env | grep -i python

printenv | grep -i python
```